# How can I install laravel on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5.6, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install laravel 5.6 via composer  on ubuntu 18.04
but i have this error:

[image: output]

Any help ?

Comment: This can be a problem on servers / VPS where the default user is root.
You've to create then another user to run composer or install it on the local machine and upload afterwards.

Comment: Which command did you use?

Comment: Would you please post the error code as text, so other people may benefit of search engines to locate your question in case they face the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, these are just some suggestions to install other packages, for example if you need console logger, you may have to install psr/log-implementation package. don't worry, your laravel installation is completed without any errors.

Comment: you mean laravel directory doesn't exists?

Comment: when create new laravel project this error

  The provided cwd does not exist.